# Java Game Object Design

Tags: java, oop

So I'm having trouble with a simple RTS design.

Basically I want to have a Model and a Controller, where people can program their own AI's to play the game, so I need some form of Interface that sits between the Model and the Controller that allows the Players to control their units without being able to 'set' things in the unit like a units stats.

So I figured to reduce code re-use I'd use a hierarchical structure for creating a unit that does different things in OO:

Player Owned Object  ->  Object with Stats (health, attack)  ->  Object that can Attack  -> Object that can move  -> Unit

So a unit is an object that: is player owned, has stats, can attack, and can move

My problem is this: How do I create some form of interface that works with all this inheritence? So that the interface returns stats if the object inherits 'Object with Stats' as well as the other 'attributes' of the unit. Is it possible with this kind of inheritence? or should I be doing this a different way?

I hope that makes sense!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a hierarchy is what you need.

The way you have this set up Objects With Stats inherit from Objects that can Attack. This implies that every object that has stats can attack - is that what you mean to say? What about a purely defensive object?

I think instead you have a number of capability Interfaces and certain objects implement certain of those so:

```
 Monster implements Attacker, Mover, StatProvider, HurtReceiver

 TreasureChest implements Attacker, StatProvider, Movable, HurtReceiver

 Map implements Movable
```

Comment: That sounds like a dangerous treasure chest!

Comment: It is, and you **really** don't want to meet the contents ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using something very similar to this, from the way my game loop was handled (and by trying to never re-use code) I ended up using abstract handlers -> an AttackHandler, MoveHandler, with these handlers being attached to the object (thus updated whenever the object was updated by the loop), which worked well!

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume you have something like this:

```
public interface Unit extends Owned, StatsProvider, Attacking, Moveable {
  // ...
}
```

and a concrete implementation like

```
public class Knight implements Unit {
  // ...
}
```

Now, for example, if we want to move all moveable objects of a player, we could say

```
List<Owned> playerOwnedObjects = getObjectsFor("Carl");  // you know what I mean...
for (Owned playerOwnedObject:playerOwnedObjects) {
  if (playerOwnedObject instanceof Moveable) {
    ((Moveable) playerOwnedObject).moveTo(getTargetLocation());
  }
}
```

Hope I haven't misunderstood your question...